# How do you put "if" statements in Twig templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

So I'm using `.get` like this:

```
$.get(base_url+'assets/js/templates/gallery_comment.html', function(template, textStatus, jqXhr)
{
    container.append(Mustache.render($(template).filter('#gallery_comment').html(), data));
});
```

To pull in the following Mustache template:

```
<script id="gallery_comment" type="text/html">
{{#has_gallery_comment}}
    {{#gallery_comment}}
        {{is_active}},
        {{is_flagged}},
        {{comment}},
    {{/gallery_comment}}
{{/has_gallery_comment}}
{{^has_gallery_comment}}
    <center><strong>Empty</strong></center>
{{/has_gallery_comment}}
</script>
```

You can see the first `if` in the template checks to see if there are any `gallery_comments`, which I set manually in JavaScript before making the GET for the template:

```
var data = new Array();
data[gallery_comments] = payload;
data['has_gallery_comments'] = (data.length > 0);
```

**QUESTION:**

How do I replace the `{{is_flagged}}` statement in the template with something like:

```
if(is_flagged == 1)
{
    echo'is_flagged: YES';
}
else
{
    echo'is_flagged: NO';
}
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED ALREADY:**

Putting this in the template does not work:

```
{% if is_flagged == 1 %}
    is flagged: YES
{% else %}
    is flagged: NO
{% endif %}
```

Comment: When you say "Putting this in the template does not work" what do you mean? What happens?

Comment: Does the if statement always equal false?  Can you try {{ dump(is_flagged) }} to output what is actually held in the is_flagged variable.